"white screen of death" on Ubuntu
I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04, but it's been a challenging experience so far. The system, or possibly the desktop manager, crashes frequently in a seemingly random manner. I installed the 24.04.1 update, which appears to have mitigated the problem slightly, but the crashes persist.
Additionally, I have two 32" monitors that used to be recognized in 4K resolution under Ubuntu 22.04. However, after the upgrade, the system no longer allows me to configure this resolution. This is frustrating as I heavily rely on 4K for my workflow.
I’ve also tried updating to the latest Nvidia driver, but it hasn’t solved the issue, and I’m out of ideas at this point.
I encountered similar issues years ago on Windows, which prompted me to switch to Linux. Instead of the infamous "blue screen of death," I seem to be dealing with what I can only describe as a "grey screen of death" on Ubuntu, which happens often.
Has anyone else experienced these issues, particularly the crashes or resolution problems? I would greatly appreciate any advice or potential fixes.


Ubuntu 24.04 relatively new and not stable as 22.04 yet. Such issues arising is expected. I would rather suggest to stay at 22.04 for a period of time if you prefer stability over new features and design.

Thanks. I will consider your suggestion (and probably follow it). However, I find it very unfortunate that the Ubuntu people have released something like this.
